# How can i insert data into temporary table by using a dynamic query in MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I want to Insert a dynamic query's result into a temporary table. How can i possible this. Plz help me...

Here is the method i tried.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_Table
(
    Id INT
);


SET @str = 'SELECT id FROM animals';

PREPARE statement1  FROM @str;


INSERT INTO temp_Table  EXECUTE statement1;
```

This is not the actual Query(i mean "SELECT id FROM animals"), the Actual contain many Conditions

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_Table SELECT id FROM animals;
```

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: Hi, Its not the actual query for Select. Which contain many conditional statement. That's why this is very complicated to use... may i have any other option... 
Thaks...

Comment: You can have any statement there, not just simple ones.